# LINQ to Entities - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I'm looking to get a better understanding on when we should look to use `IEnumerable` over `IQueryable`with LINQ to Entities.

With really basic calls to the database, `IQueryable` is way quicker, but when do i need to think about using an `IEnumerable` in its place?

Where is an `IEnumerable` optimal over an `IQueryable`??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, IQueryables are executed by a query provider (for example a database) and some operations cannot be or should not be done by the database. For example, if you want to call a C# function (here as an example, capitalize a name correctly) using a value you got from the database you may try something like;

```
db.Users.Select(x => Capitalize(x.Name)) // Tries to make the db call Capitalize.
        .ToList();
```

Since the `Select` is executed on an IQueryable, and the underlying database has no idea about your `Capitalize` function, the query will fail. What you can do instead is to get the correct data from the database and convert the IQueryable to an IEnumerable (which is basically just a way to iterate through collections in-memory) to do the rest of the operation in local memory, as in;

```
db.Users.Select(x => x.Name)             // Gets only the name from the database
        .AsEnumerable()                  // Do the rest of the operations in memory
        .Select(x => Capitalize(x))      // Capitalize in memory
        .ToList();
```

The most important thing when it comes to performance of IQueryable vs. IEnumerable from the side of EF, is that you should *always try to filter the data using an IQueryable* to get as little data as possible to convert to an IEnumerable. What the `AsEnumerable` call basically does is to tell the database "give me the data as it is filtered now", and if you didn't filter it, you'll get everything fetched to memory, even data you may not need.

Answer (score 3):

`IEnumerable` represents a sequence of elements which you enumerate one by one until you find the answer you need, so for example if I wanted all entities that had some property greater than 10, I'd need to go through each one in turn and return only those that matched. Pulling every row of a database table into memory in order to do this would not maybe be a great idea.

`IQueryable` on the other hand represents a set of elements on which operations like filtering can be deferred to the underlying data source, so in the filtering case, if I were to implement `IQueryable` on top of a custom data source (or use LINQ to Entities!) then I could give the hard work of filtering / grouping etc to the data source (e.g. a database).

The major downside of `IQueryable` is that implementing it is pretty hard - queries are constructed as Expression trees which as the implementer you then have to parse in order to resolve the query. If you're not planning to write a provider though then this isn't going to hurt you.

Another aspect of IQueryable that it's worth being aware of (although this is really just a generic caveat about passing processing off to another system that may make different assumptions about the world) is that you may find things like string comparison work in the manner they are supported in the source system, not in the manner they are implemented by the consumer, e.g. if your source database is case-insensitive but your default comparison in .NET is case-sensitive.